# trying to determine an approach to my programming issue

Tags: xml, parsing, architecture, excel-2003

I got this issue. I have about 10k xml files containing a bunch of performance data. I need to parce, and then import them into excel so I can generate a graph out of it.

I am trying to decide what would be the best approach to solving this. I can't do a direct import because excel doesn't recognize it as a valid xml format. (excel gives me schema not recognized or some thing)

the file format goes something like this: (I have only included the useful information.)
name of the file goes like this: YYDDMM.startOfPMPeriod_endOfPMPeriod
and in the file:

```
<time stamp>
<PM category1>
<PM category2>
<PM category3>
...

<sub system 1>
<result>1</result>
<result>2.0</result>
...

<sub system 2>
<result>0.221</result>
<result>2.0</result>
...

<sub system n>
<result>1</result>
<result>2.0</result>
```

And there are approx 10k these files. each files goes for about 6k lines. :)

I am not sure about how to approach this. I got the basic logic of it:

```
while (we got more files to read) 
    read a file
    parse PM category and timestamp
          while (not end of file)
               reading in results data and the subsystems
    //store it in an array of some sort, but I am not sure about the structure of it
//once we are done with our files
pass the array to excel, (somehow, maybe as a CSV?)
```

What do you guys think would be the best approach to solve this?  My programming skills are limited. I am familiar with java, c++ and bash scripting. 3 dimensional arrays are beyond me. I have enough trouble with 2 dimensions. :) My most complicated assignment was to make a multi-threaded banking application with java.

Davy

Update: it is for excel 2003
and the excel table should look like this: and I can't attach images so you will have to make do with this:

```
                      timestamp 1   timestamp2  timestamp 3
subsystem 1 pm cat 1
            pm cat 2
            pm cat 3

subsystem 2 pm cat 1
            pm cat 2
            pm cat 3
```

Comment: Ops, how silly of me. Excel 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you start by by inserting a piece of data using [VSTO](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20923).  Once you insert a single row, you can re-use what you learned to insert multiple rows.

XML to an NxN array is an overly complicated means to attack XML parsing.  XML parsing can be effectively accomplished via [XPATH](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) or [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).  If you have no experience with LINQ, perhaps XPATH is a better start.

First figure out how you want the rows to look in excel, then extract the XML accordingly.  This will avoid N x N arrays and give you a goal of producing a known output.

Comment: Is the VSTO included in the microsoft Primary Interop Assemblies? cause that's what the link gave me.

Comment: It seems that VSTO requires visual studio, would visual basic 2010 express suffice?

Comment: Hi all, I fixed the import issue to excel. excel 2003 can create mapping based on your xml file, allowing you to import ONE xml file. But multiple imports still fails.

Comment: great news, turns out one of my coworkers has written a macro for this, except its kind of buggy, at least i don't have to start from scratch. Thanks for P.Brian.Mackey for his help.